# Why doesn't it swap?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Arrays {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x;
        int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ;
        for(int a = 1; a < 10; a++){
            x = arr[a];
            arr[a] = arr[10-a];
            arr[10-a] = x;
        }
        for(int a = 0; a<10; a++){
            System.out.println(arr[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

The question is easy: why doesn't the array member swap places?

Comment: It does. Then it swaps back.

Comment: just keep the size of the array as 3 with 3 elements in it, then do the **dry run** of the code. You will get the error. Dry run and debugging are our best friends...

Comment: Print all the swaps it does if the first comment is unclear.

Comment: well what if I tell you I don't know what dry running is

Comment: User paper and pencil and follow your code step by step, simulating the action of the computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your swapping function works. You just need to take care of few things. 
1. Run the *swap* only till the first half part of the array; else it will (swap back and) result in the original array. 
2. Array index starts from 0 and not 1.

Here's the code you need

```
int x;
int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int len = arr.length; // saving length in a int variable

for(int a = 0; a < len / 2; a++){
  x = arr[a];                        
  arr[a] = arr[len - 1 - a];  //notice the 'len - 1' here as index starts from 0. So last element is 'length of array - 1'
  arr[len - 1 - a] = x;
}

for(int a = 0; a < len; a++){
  System.out.print(arr[a]);
}
```

Comment: Hi @GuillaumeF., I tried with odd lengths too and it worked fine :)
int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
I would appreciate if you upvote my comment and answer as it will give me enough points and make me eligible to post comments on other's solutions :)

Comment: Oh no you are right, because the center doesn't have to swap, so it works indeed. Meaculpa

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example, You want to reverse the array.

```
for(int a = 0; a < arr.lenght/2 ; a++){            
  x = arr[a];
  arr[a] = arr[9-a];
  arr[9-a] = x;
}
```

Because after reaching to the **half** of the array, the values are **swapping back** again to their position again.

You need to dry run this by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Because you swap twice, you should just swap to the middle point and stop

public class Arrays {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int x;
    int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ;
    for(int a = 0; a < (arr.length / 2); a++){
        x = arr[a];
        int swapWithIndex = arr.length - 1 - a;
        arr[a] = arr[swapWithIndex];
        arr[swapWithIndex] = x;
    }
    for(int a = 0; a<10; a++){
        System.out.println(arr[a]);
    }
}
```

}